# Why is the scheme of isomorphisms of sheaves affine over the base?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Suppose $S$ a noetherian base scheme, $X \to S$ is projective and $F, G$ are coherent $\mathcal O_X$-modules. Then by EGA (7.7.8) and (7.7.9) there exists a scheme $H = \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}_X(F, G)$, affine over $S$, which represents the functor
$$(f: T \to S) \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{X_T}(f^*F, f^*G).$$
On $X_H$ there is a universal homomorphism $\varphi: F_H \to G_H$. Considering the exact sequence
$$0 \to \ker \varphi \to F_H \xrightarrow{\varphi} G_H \to \operatorname{coker} \varphi \to 0,$$
one can check that the open set $$\underline{\operatorname{Isom}}_X(F, G):= H \setminus (\operatorname{supp}(\ker \varphi) \cup \operatorname{supp}(\operatorname{coker} \varphi)) \subset H$$ represents the functor
$$(f: T \to S) \mapsto \operatorname{Isom}_{X_T}(f^*F, f^*G).$$
In [1, Section 2.1], Jason Starr and Johan de Jong write that $\underline{\operatorname{Isom}}_X(F, G)$ is affine over the base $S$. Why is that true? In general, opens of affine schemes are not affine.

[1] Jason Starr, Johan de Jong; *Almost proper GIT stacks and Discriminant Avoidance*

Comment: I actually don't know how to prove this but I would expect this to be linked somehow to the fact that $Gl_n$ is an affine group scheme  embedded inside  $Mat_n$. (Sorry for the vague answer I'll try to see if I can write down some true stuff).

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio Discussing a bit with my professor, I realized that actually Starr and de Jong only claim the affine-ness in the case where $F$ and $G$ are locally free, and then I think this is exactly what you mean: Locally it should be $Gl_n \times X$.

Comment: I believe that EGA IV Section 8.8 only works if $F$ is flat.  So if you want the Hom in each direction to be representable I believe you need to assume that both $F$ and $G$ are locally free.

Comment: The EGA reference, I think, is in EGA III-2. It is about representing Hom sheaves of coherent sheaves by a *sheaf*, not a scheme. And indeed there is a flatness assumption on $\mathscr{F}$. In any case, taking $X=S$, $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{O}_X$, and $\mathscr{G}=$ a skyscraper sheaf at a closed point, I am sure there is no scheme $H$ as in the question.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Actually, the assumption should be that $G$ is flat (my notation is opposite to EGA), so this excludes your example. And if $\mathcal N$ is the sheaf from EGA III-2 (7.7.8), then I think $H = \underline{\operatorname{Spec}}_S(S^* \mathcal N)$ should do it. See also Thm 3.5 in Nitsure's [Construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590.pdf).

Comment: Silly question: what is $X_H$?

Comment: @DavidRoberts $X_H = X \times_S H$. Similarly, $F_H$ and $G_H$ are the pull-backs of $F$ and $G$ to $X_H$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly  Of course you are correct.  I wrote the wrong reference in EGA.  Right now I am teaching this material, and material from your book, so I should have had the correct reference.

Comment: @red_trumpet, Ok, thanks. I assumed it was some kind of base change, but I couldn't figure out to where!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I realized Jason Starr and Johan de Jong only claim that $H = \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}_S(F, G)$ is affine if $F$ and $G$ are locally free. In that case, if $U = \operatorname{Spec}(A) \subset H$ is such that $F$ and $G$ are free of rank $n$ on $U$, we get
$$H_U = Gl_n(A) = \operatorname{Spec}A[X_{ij}|i,j = 1, \dotsc, n][\frac{1}{\det}],$$
so $H$ is affine over $S$.

Answer (score 0):

This result is true quite generally. One reference is:

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08K9

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly's [example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407732/why-is-the-scheme-of-isomorphisms-of-sheaves-affine-over-the-base#comment1045761_407732) shows that it is not true without *some* hypothesis.